# Is it safe to use Gradle aar (Android archive) packages in my Android projects?

Tags: android, security, android-studio, gradle

My app is using some view/layout libraries from github, which I included as dependencies in my build.gradle file. My question is, how do the IDE (i'm using Android Studio)/Gradle pull these dependency files from whatever repo and build into my final .apk when I build the project (so that the creator of the .aar might be able to add new contents in the future and they'll somehow get included in my future build?), and what are some security risks for now and down the road(when I update my app in the future)? Thanks!